# While integrating ZF1 and ZF2, how to access ZF1 modules,models from ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

While integrating ZF1 and ZF2, how to access ZF1 modules,models from ZF2.Try to
to register ZF1 autoloader in your ZF2 bootstrap but it does not work.ZF1 and ZF2 run together successfully and Zend2 can access library but it is not accessing zend1 modules and models.

Comment: Maybe take a look here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/migration/zf1_zf2_parallel.html

Comment: "it doesn't work"  - Voting to close this question as It is way to broad, try being more specific. If you have already tried something update your question with the actual code.